# Nothing is loaded into my jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery

Before I had the following jQuery:

```
var dialogDiv = "<div id='" + dialogId + "'></div>";

$(dialogDiv).load(href, function () {
    ...
```

It worked fine.

Now I changed a little bit like this:

```
var dialogDiv = "<div id='" + dialogId + "' class='modal hide fade'><div class='modal-body'><p class='body'></p></div></div>";

$('.modal-body p.body').load(href, function () {
    ...
```

Now nothing is loaded into my jQuery dialog. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your outer div set to `display: none`?

Comment: are you adding that dialogdiv to the page before you try to load()? Your selector will parse html for '.modal-body p.body', but if it is not there yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that those elements don't exist in the DOM yet. Wrap it in a jQuery object:

```
var $dialogDiv = $("<div id='" + dialogId + "' class='modal hide fade'><div class='modal-body'><p class='body'></p></div></div>");

$dialogDiv.find('.modal-body p.body').load(href, function () {
```

**EDIT:** Eventually you'll have to insert that object in the DOM. You can chain `insertAfter($bla)` to the `load()` event.

Comment: +1, but please allow me to add a proper explanation. In bronzato's first example he uses the variable `dialogDiv` to add the `load` event, in the second example he uses a selector which only applies to added DOM. Because `dialogDiv` was not added, it can't find the element. Elclanrs' solution is to search for the element within the variable, instead of the added DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Does class 'hide' shows the dialog div? If true the target element is not visible ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get an element which is not yet available in the DOM tree, you can either inject it before calling load() or wrap it into a jQuery object before loading content:

```
var dialogDiv = $("<div id='" + dialogId + "' class='modal hide fade'><div class='modal-body'><p class='body'></p></div></div>");

$('.modal-body p.body', dialogDiv).load(href, function () { ... }
```