# My html is not injected as supposed in my jquery dialog

Tags: jquery

I have the following jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        url: href,
        context: document.body,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            // Prepare & show dialog
            $(dialogDiv).find('.modal-body p.body').html(data);
            ...
```

I have some html in 'data'. I'm sure because I display it in an alert box. I try to inject this html with the last line in the script above. When I inspect the DOM, I don't see my html in it.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you see in the DOM? What valud does `data` have? What is `dialogDiv`? When you run this what do you see: `alert($(dialogDiv).length)`.

Comment: How are you assigning a value to dialogDiv?

Comment: It could be that `$(dialogDiv).find('.modal-body p.body')` isn't returning the element you expect (or no element at all).

Comment: Please see the OP's other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223656/nothing-is-loaded-into-my-jquery-dialog and you will get an idea of how the `diaglogDiv` is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you defined `dialogDiv` before ajax call (meaning it will be global inside the response method) then why you don't just use

`dialogDiv.find('.modal-body p.body').html(data);`

instead of

`$(dialogDiv).find('.modal-body p.body').html(data);`

Also make sure that `.modal-body p.body` actually exist **before** showing the popup. 
I'm guessing, that your dialog box creates its markup when you showing (or initializing) it. 
And here you try to inject html to non-existant element yet. 
Try to investigate more, hope it helps.

For a quick check, try first show your dialog and then insert html and see if it's been inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `dataType` parameter to the [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call. In my experience, jQuery's intelligent data type guessing isn't 100% perfect.

```
$.ajax({
    url: href,
    context: document.body,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (data) {},
    ...
});
```

Comment: But he sees markup in the alert, so how does this change anything?

Comment: The data is received correctly but `html()`ing it will fail. That's what failed for me on a project recently.

Comment: I'm assuming here that he's looked at the alert box and said "Yep, that's correctly formatted HTML".  Guess I shouldn't assume though, should I? ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that data is html, try appendTo.

```
var $modal=$(dialogDiv).find('.modal-body p.body');
$(data).appendTo($modal);
```